# State not updating in Component

Tags: reactjs, state

Hey I am trying to create a simple to-do list and I have added the components necessary. However, the state is not being updated in the Title {this.state.data.length} and the TodoList {this.state.data}. A Codepen and the relevant code is below.

https://codepen.io/skasliwal12/pen/BREYXK

```
const TodoForm = ({addTodo}) => {
  let input;
  return (
    <div>
    <input ref={node => {input = node;}} />
    <button onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addTodo(input.value);
        input.value='';
    }}> +
    </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const TodoList = ({todos}) => {
    let todoNodes = todos.map(todo => {
        return <li>{todo}</li>
    });
    return <div> {todoNodes} </div>;
}

const Title = ({todoCount}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>To-do App {todoCount} items</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class TestApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data : [] }
  }

  addTodo(val) {
    let todo = {text: val}
    this.state.data.push(todo);
    this.setState = ({data: this.state.data});
    console.log('state updated?')
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Title todoCount={this.state.data.length}/>
        <TodoForm addTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)}/>
        <TodoList todos={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply it is important that you DO NOT MUTATE the state like you are doing here

```
this.state.data.push(todo);
```

It is hard to debug and adds side effects that are hard to keep track of. Following your approach you should copy the state to a var, update that var and then pass it as the new field in your state. Which could work but it's also something I do not recommend. A general good approach is to to compute the new state based on the old one

```
// this.state.data.push(todo); You can remove this line
this.setState(prevState => ({ data: prevState.data.concat(todo) }))
```

This will fix your issue and avoid mutating the state, which is something you should never do, only update the state using the `setState` method.

I also updated your `TodoList` which was not displaying properly, you have to access the `text` field of the todo in order to show something.

```
const TodoList = ({todos}) => {
    let todoNodes = todos.map(todo => {
        return <li>{todo.text}</li>
    });
    return <div> {todoNodes} </div>;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmRVmX?editors=1010